# accessing length of an array inside an object gives me 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, square-bracket

I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when trying to access length of an array inside of an object that I get from mapstatetoprops... In my actions folder, i created a function getuserdata that makes an api call and successfully returns an object. in my component i call this.props.getuserdata in componentdidMount, and i mapstatetoprops currentUser state  with getUserdata... although tt returns an object, it does not allow me to access the length of one of the properties arrays....
my mapstatetoprops writes:

**currentUser: state.currentUser.getUserData**

components folder

```
    class Users extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserData();
    this.props.getOtherUsers();
   }

  render() {
      console.log(this.props.currentUser.myStocks.length,'current user')
      
      return (
      <Container>
      
      </Container>
    )
  }
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
   currentUser: state.currentUser.getUserData, 
    filteredUsers: state.filteredUsers.getOtherUsers,
    getUsersError: state.users.getUsersError
  };
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserData, getOtherUsers }),
  requireAuth
)(Users);
```

actions folder:

```
    export const getUserData = () => async (dispatch) => {
   try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/user/profile', {
      headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') },
    });
    // console.log(data.myStocks[0],'inform')
    dispatch({ type: GET_USER_DATA, payload: data });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_USER_DATA_ERROR,
      serverError: e,
      clientError: 'Something went wrong please refresh try again',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does "this.props.getUserData" modify "this.props.currentUser" in any way via state change? Because it looks like you are passing currentUser as a function, not an array. What does console logging current user give you?

Comment: I am getting a console of an object with the current users properties

Comment: Well you didn't post any usefull code, like the one where the `.length` occured or the structure of the data sent by the api. But you can debug it very easyly by putting `console.log(apiAnswer)` then `console.log(apiAnswer.theArray);` and so on... then you will see your error.

Comment: Gotcha well if the myStocks property is not on that list then it isn't being returned by the API or if the request is an AJAX request then maybe you are accessing the property before it has been initialized. My guess.

Answer (score 1):

If `this.props.currentUser` is supposed to be obtained by `this.props.getUserData()` maybe the problem is that you API call is not finish while react use the `render` method.

Comment: right. i access getUserdata api data in my mapstatetoprops.    currentUser: state.currentUser.getUserData,